# CSS - Media Queries not working properly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm new to media queries, and I've watched a few tutorials on the best practices, but it seems i can't get mine to work..

I created a simple text div to make sure it even works, and I'm trying to have the `background-color` of the div change to blue once the `width` of the browser is smaller than `500px`.

Does anybody know what I'm missing?

```css
#text_box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #test_box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="text_box">Test</div>
```

Here is my [demo](http://codepen.io/stinkytofu3311/pen/pydZPQ)

Comment: @media screen (max-width:500px) { 
    #text_box {
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
        background-color:blue;
    } 
}

Comment: Like this? (See Example above) Seems to still not work for me.

Comment: Your code does work, fix the typo and change it from max width to min width for example and you'll see it working fine. Remember you're saying a MAXIMUM of 500px, if your screen is larger than that, it won't show the change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a typo inside your media query in your `id`,it is not `test_box`, but `text_box`.

plus you don't need to repeat properties already set before, if they have the same value.

```css
#text_box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #text_box {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="text_box">Test</div>
```

Comment: Lol Funny thing is i noticed the typo, but then changed it to what Martin said. Which sadly did not fix it. Then i went back and added what Dippas mentioned, and it fixed it. Whew. Thanks guy! I knew it was something simple...